# JOptionPane Issue in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

How to fix the problem
Access restriction: The type JOptionPane is not accessible due to restriction on 
 required library C:\Program Files\Java\j2re1.4.2_05\lib\rt.jar

Comment: What is producing that message?  And out of curiosity, why are you using a version of Java that’s 12½ years old?

Comment: what should i do now